# Do machine readable specifications exist somewhere for NXP processors?

Tags: arm

this would really be helpful for getting the info on bitfields, instead of extracting them from the header file(s).
Any link or tip will be greatly appreciated.
Helmut

Comment: just download the documentation for the part from NXP.  usually a datasheet and/or a reference manual.  Some vendors use different terminology for the names of the documents.  and some split the addresses across documents (one might have the base address, another the offsets from the base).   but it should all be there NXP is pretty good on documentation.  one of the better ones.

Comment: Would a CMSIS SVD file contain the information you want?

Comment: YES, that is exactly the information I was looking for. And I even found the .SVD file for my particular processor. Many thanks, Andy, you made my day.